# OR operator inside objective C switch statment

Tags: iphone, ios, switch-statement

I am wondering if its possible to have a an (||)"or" or (&&)"and" operator in ta switch statment case.

this is what I am thinking of.

```
switch (orientation) {
            case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            {
                case (UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight):
             }
            break;
//...
```

if anyone can help me out I would really appreciate it :)

Comment: AND in switch makes no sense - you can't have `orientation` with two different values at the same time. OR is implemented easily, see answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

&& is not possible, but you can achieve something similar to || by having multiple cases without a break:

```
switch (orientation)
{
   case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
       // ...
       break;

   case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
   case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
       // ...
       break;
}
```

You can of course also work with `orientation` inside your case block (ie evaluate it further)

Answer (score 4):

`OR` is implied in the structure of `switch` with missing `break`:

```
switch (orientation) {
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        case (UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight: {
        }
        break;
}
```

`AND` does not make sense, because one variable cannot be equal to two different integer numbers at the same time.